# strange behaviour when vector elemnts are set using indexing

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, c++14

Trying to copy all elements from one `vector` to another using indexing as shown in code snippet. As far as I understand, setting/getting an element in vector using index(I'm aware about "at" and its benefits) is allowed in `C++`.

If I set an element in `vector a` using index, it works as expected. For `vector b` also, If push_back is used, it works as expected.

```
int main() 
{   
vector<int> a{1,3,6,10,56,9};
vector<int> b;
b.reserve(a.size());
cout << "1. a[2]: " << a[2] << endl;
a[2] = 100;
cout << "2. a[2]: " << a[2] << endl;
for(int i=0; i<a.size(); ++i)
{
    b[i] = a[i];
}
cout << "1. b.size() : " << b.size() << endl;


for(int i=0; i<a.size(); ++i)
{
    b.push_back(a[i]);
}
cout << "2. b.size() : " << b.size() << endl;
return 0;
}
```

I'm finding it difficult to understand this behaviour of `vector`.

Note: I know this is not a suggested way of copying `vector` as we have multiple other options which both convenient and effective.

output:

```
1. a[2]: 6
2. a[2]: 100
1. b.size() : 0
2. b.size() : 6
```

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  You need `resize`, not `reserve` for `b.reserve(a.size());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::vector::reserve()` is not the same as `std::vector::resize()`.

`b.reserve(a.size())` does not change `b`'s size. You'll need to use `b.resize(a.size())` for that.

---

```
vector<int> a{1,3,6,10,56,9};
vector<int> b;
b.resize(a.size());
```

or create `b` with the right size to start with.

```
vector<int> a{1,3,6,10,56,9};
vector<int> b(a.size());
```

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector::reserve` doesn't actually create any elements, it only reserves the memory for them, so when using `push_back` or `emplace_back`, `vector` won't have to reallocate the memory to make space for more elements.

If you want to construct the objects, instead of reserving the memory for them, use `std::vector::resize`

Answer (score 1):

You have undefined behaviour at

```
b[i] = a[i];
```

`b[i]` doesn't exist so you are accessing the vector out of bounds since its size is 0.